# "Has led to" or "led to"

Tags: past-perfect

My friend wrote a phrase in his textbook:

> "All of above **led to** three major alliances to rise".

I suggest him to change it to

> All of the above **has led to the rise of** the three major alliances."

However he argues that perfect tense is not good here. Which version is more correct?

Comment: It's partly a stylistic choice, and partly a matter of exact context, whether to use Simple Past *(**led**)* or Present Perfect *(**has / have** led)*. The latter implies a strong connection to "time of utterance" (so it wouldn't be suitable if you're talking about events long in the past, and those alliances no longer exist). The choice between singular/plural ***has/have*** depends on whether you're thinking in terms of ***all of the above*** being a single collective reason / predisposing factor, or several distinct ones

Comment: Your friend's error is the use of 'to rise' following 'led to'. The answer by @Acme_54 and comment by FumbleFingers explain the effect of and reasons for using Past and Past Perfect tenses beautifully but, if your friend's choice suits his meaning, it should use either 'the rise of' in the way you suggested or 'rising' instead of 'to rise'

Comment: @FumbleFingers what if said alliances still exist?

Comment: As pointed out, *Present Perfect implies a strong connection to "time of utterance"*. What that means is that *in principle* you might want to use it if the alliances still exist ***and if*** you want to draw attention to that fact. But in practice even most native speakers are barely aware of this (if at all). So I suggest you do the same as the average native speaker and try to *avoid* using complex tenses unnecessarily. If it's important to the conversation that the alliances still exist, that will be contextually obvious without all this superfluous "fine-tuning" of verb forms.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Grammar note: "led to" = simple past tense; "has led to" = present perfect tense.

In general, US English tends to prefer the past tense form, when other variants, such as UK English, tend to make more use of present perfect forms.

The present perfect "has led to" suggests a situation lasting until the present, or with a strong connection to it; in contrast, the simple past form "led to" describes an action completed in the past.
Without further context from the text at hand, it is difficult to decide on the right option for the target audience in question.

Comment: So, for example, if discussing 19th-century Spanish politics, "led to" would be the way to go. However, if referring to the present day, "has led to the current situation" could be an accurate description of the ongoing debacle...

Comment: Saying that the U.S. uses the past tense more often, while true, isn't very helpful—the past perfect is common in the U.S., and there are times when we feel we have to use it. Similarly, the past tense is common in the U.K.

Comment: So in my case, if some sequence of the events in the past has led to forming the alliances in the past I should use the past perfect tense, right? Because the action (lead to) took place before another event in the past (forming of the alliances). As per this exlpanation: http://esl.fis.edu/grammar/rules/pastperf.htm Sorry, the tense system is really confusing.

Comment: @Peter Shor: As [this US linguist](http://separatedbyacommonlanguage.blogspot.co.uk/2006/08/present-perfect.html) points out, *The "death" of the present perfect in AmE has been exaggerated.* Noting his contrast between AmE *Did you eat yet?* and BrE *Have you eaten already?* I'm inclined to think that if it weren't for the fact that Americans are much more likely to use "do-support", it might well have been that AmE would continue to favour the complexity of present perfect [as they do with the subjunctive](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/76578/) (imho, AmE likes "correct" forms).

Comment: @FumbleFingers: I agree with that link this is the frequency illusion ... American speakers don't feel any obligation to use the present perfect with *just, already,* or *yet.* And apparently many British speakers do. So people notice the difference in these sentences, and in other cases where the grammar differs, and think it's part of a much more widespread phenomenon.

Comment: @Peter Shor: Well, I may be wrong, but [my theory, which is mine](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=U6zWjUhfj-M) is the "more widespread phenomenon" is that *traditionally correct syntax* matters more in AmE as a "social status" indicator (in BrE we may use *dialect/accent* more for that). But that's only really at the upper end of social strata - at the other end the US has historically always had far more non-native speakers anyway, and *they* tend to promote simpler forms and "regularization" (do-support is simple, regular, and I'd guess *easier*, on average).

Comment: @FumbleFingers: that's probably correct. Back in the 1960s, most of the country probably couldn't tell an upper-class Boston accent (e.g. JFK) from a lower-class Boston accent, and I've read that they were quite distinct. And it was probably similar in other regions—certainly in the South.